# How to add all integers for duplicates elements in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following HashMap:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

How can I sum up all the integers for the duplicates String? or is there a better way to do it using Set?

for example, if I add these elements:

```
car 100

TV 140

car 5

charger 10

TV 10
```

I want the list to have:

```
car 105

TV 150

charger 10
```

Comment: There won't be duplicates, the key in a map is unique.

Comment: The key in a HashMap is unique, therefore the map won't allow for duplicate values.

Comment: @J-me I supposed you meant "duplicate keys", because a map can have duplicate values.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo That's what I meant, yeah. Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot add duplicate keys in map.
But if I understood what you want, the below code may help you:

```
    if (map.containsKey(key))
        map.put(key, map.get(key) + newValue);
    else
        map.put(key, newValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe your question is: how do I put key/value pairs into a map in a way that changes the value rather than replacing it, for the same key.

Java has a `Map` method specifically for this purpose:

```
map.merge(key, value, (v, n) -> v + n);
```

This will add the value if the key isn't in the map. Otherwise it'll replace the current value with the sum of the current and new values.

The `merge` method was introduced in Java 8.

Comment: I believe it is time we see java 8 as a standard @OneManCrew and everything below to be legacy code... It was release on March 18, 2014 ... And is the LTS at this time.

Comment: @AxelH That won’t make all those millions of lines of Java code still running in pre-JDK8 vms magically disappear. Just upgrading is not an option for everyone.

Comment: I didn't say that @EdwinDalorzo but thinking like that, we can ask Oracle to stop adding feature to Java since we still have application running on older version (I know, I worked in a place running java 5 and 6...). This is not valid reason to downvote answers on questions that doesn't specifiy working on "older" version.

Comment: @AxelH And I would add the following : ***if the user do not specify the version of Java within the question, one can go with the latest maintained version of java***

Comment: @AxelH All I'm saying is that the "what about Java <8?" question should probably be honored with more than "just upgrade". And I didn't downvoted your answer, I in fact, upvoted it.

Comment: You mean "what about Java<8 **????** " or "java 8 and above **!!!!** " @EdwinDalorzo ;-) I never said to upgrade at all ... but to see java 8 features as a standard that doesn't need to be marked with a special tag (what those comments lets assume).PS: I wasn't assuming you had downvoted, that was not meant to you :)

Answer (score 1):

For [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and higher

You may just want to use the [**`Map#merge`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method. It is the easiest way possible. If the key does not exist, it will add it, if it does exist, it will perform the merge operation.

```
map.merge("car", 100, Integer::sum);
map.merge("car", 20, Integer::sum);

System.out.println(map); // {car=120}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add "TV" for the second time, the first value (140) will be override because you cannot have duplicated keys on Map implementation. If you want to increment the value you will need to check if the key "TV" already exists and then increment/add the value.

For example:

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
   value += map.get(key);
} 
map.put(key, value)
```

Answer (score -1):

**HashMap dosen't save duplicates keys!**

**You can extend the HashMap Class(JAVA >= 8):**

```
public class MyHashMap2 extends HashMap<String, Integer>{

@Override
public Integer put(String key, Integer value) {
    return merge(key, value, (v, n) -> v + n);
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
   MyHashMap2 list3=new MyHashMap2();
    list3.put("TV", 10);
    list3.put("TV", 20);
    System.out.println(list3);
 }
}
```

**Or You can aggregate the `HashMap` and replace the put method to add to the previous value the new value.**

```
HashMap<String, Integer> list = new HashMap<>();
        list.put("TV", 10);
        list.put("TV", 20);
        System.out.println(list);

        MyHashMap list2 = new MyHashMap();
        list2.put("TV", 10);
        list2.put("TV", 20);
        System.out.println(list2);
//OUTPUT:
//{TV=20}
//MyHashMap [List={TV=30}]



public class MyHashMap implements Map<String, Integer>{
        HashMap<String, Integer> list = new HashMap<>();

        public MyHashMap() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return list.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
            return list.containsKey(key);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
            return  list.containsValue( value);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(Object key) {
            return list.get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer put(String key, Integer value) {
             if(list.containsKey(key))
                 list.put(key, list.get(key)+value);
                else
                    list.put(key, value);
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer remove(Object key) {

            return list.remove(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends Integer> m) {
            list.putAll(m);

        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            list.clear();


        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> keySet() {
            return list.keySet();
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<Integer> values() {
            return list.values();
        }

        @Override
        public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet() {
            return list.entrySet();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyHashMap [list=" + list + "]";
        }


    }
```

you can try the code here:https://ideone.com/Wl4Arb

Comment: Your last solution is pointless... using a member variable `HashMap<String, Integer>` used in every implemented method calling exactly the same method... You have created a proxy that doesn't add anything except for `put` (and you loose the generic types). Just extends `HashMap` the same way you did in the first solution. This will reduce the complexity in your answer;